# Calling a function for a period of time

Tags: c++, c, linux, time, timestamp

I want to make a call - either a function call or doing some condition for a PERIOD of time ... typically 10 - 20 seconds.

I would get some user input for the amount of time and do that ...

What is the proper function to use on Linux/Unix systems?

gettimeofday seems to be the way to go ... or perhaps  time_t time(time_t *t) ... seems simple. What is preferred?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want the function call to last for 10-20 seconds, or do you want to sleep for 10-20 seconds and then call it? How long a function call lasts is pretty much up the function itself.

Comment: I want to call a function for about 10 to 20 seconds ... or really call anything ... the issue is how do I best MEASURE the time ... there are many overlapping Unix/Posix time functions.

Comment: do you have an limit on how many times you want to call this function?  One time?  Millions of times?  If it is one time, you may want to look into registering a timer preset for 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

So is it something like this you want? This will repeatedly call myfunc() for the next 20 seconds. So could do 1 call (if myfunc takes at least 20 seconds to run) or hundreds of calls (of myfunc() takes a few milliseconds to complete):

```
#include <time.h>

void myfunc()
{
    /* do something */
}    

int main()
{
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    while ((now - start) <= 20) {
        myfunc();
        now = time(NULL);
    }
}
```

It's probably worth asking what you're ultimately trying to achieve. If this is for profiling (e.g., what's the average amount of time function f takes to execute), then you might want to look at other solutions - e.g., using the built-in profiling that gcc gives you (when building code with the "-pg" option), and analyzing with gprof.

Comment: Best answer for a poorly formulated question, +1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like so

```
#include <ctime>
/*
your function here
*/

    int main()
    {
        double TimeToRunInSecs = ...;
        clock_t c = clock();
        while(double(clock()-c)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC < TimeToRunInSecs)
       {
          myFunc();
       }
    }
```

the standard clock() function returns number of SOMETHING from the process start. In one second there are CLOCK_PER_SEC SOMETHINGs :)

HTH

Comment: This is almost certainly not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Amigable: Why do you think so? I think this is exactly what he wants.

Comment: CPU time is very dependent on CPU performance, load and a lot of factors. I may be wrong, but in any case I think the question needs work.

Answer (score 0):

I could do a

`time_t current_time = time(0);`

and measure off of that ... but is there a preferred way ... mainly this is a best practices kind of question ....

x

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things..

If you want to ensure that the function takes a Time X to complete, irrespective of how long the actual code within the function took, do something like this (highly pseudo code)

```
class Delay
{
  public:
    Delay(long long delay) : _delay(delay) // in microseconds
    {
       ::gettimeofday(_start, NULL); // grab the start time...
    }

    ~Delay()
    {
      struct timeval end;

      ::gettimeofday(end, NULL); // grab the end time
      long long ts = _start.tv_sec * 1000000 + _start.tv_usec;
      long long tse = end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec;

      long long diff = tse - ts;
      if (diff < _delay)
      {
        // need to sleep for the difference...
        // do this using select;
        // construct a struct timeval (same as required for gettimeofday)
        fd_set rfds;
        struct timeval tv;
        int retval;

        FD_ZERO(&rfds);

        diff = _delay - diff; // calculate the time to sleep

        tv.tv_sec = diff / 1000000;
        tv.tv_usec = diff % 1000000;

        retval = select(0, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        // should only get here when this times out...
      }
    }
  private:
    struct timeval _start;   
};
```

Then define an instance of this Delay class at the top of your function to delay - should do the trick... (this code is untested and could have bugs in it, I just typed it to give you an idea..)